# JSON Group by Name and then Display Latest Record

Tags: javascript, json, filtering

Using only JavaScript, I need to

1. Group by code.
2. Get latest modifieddate.
3. Display total grouped code as Count.

**Starting JSON Result**

```
[
{"ID":1,"code":"AAA","modifieddate":"2019-06-01","user":"John"},
{"ID":2,"code":"AAA","modifieddate":"2019-06-02","user":"Jane"},
{"ID":3,"code":"AAA","modifieddate":"2019-06-03","user":"Sue"},
{"ID":4,"code":"BBB","modifieddate":"2019-06-10","user":"Rick"},
{"ID":5,"code":"CCC","modifieddate":"2019-06-11","user":"Joe"}
]
```

**Desired JSON Result set**

```
[
{"ID":3,"code":"AAA","modifieddate":"2019-06-03","user":"Sue","Count":"3"},
{"ID":4,"code":"BBB","modifieddate":"2019-06-10","user":"Rick","Count":"1"},
{"ID":5,"code":"CCC","modifieddate":"2019-06-11","user":"Joe","Count":"1"}
]
```

1. Tried using reduce method.
2. I do not have access to modify the server side API code.
3. I am using Aurelia JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you:

```
let array = [
  {"ID":1,"code":"AAA","modifieddate":"2019-06-01","user":"John"},
  {"ID":2,"code":"AAA","modifieddate":"2019-06-02","user":"Jane"},
  {"ID":3,"code":"AAA","modifieddate":"2019-06-03","user":"Sue"},
  {"ID":4,"code":"BBB","modifieddate":"2019-06-10","user":"Rick"},
  {"ID":5,"code":"CCC","modifieddate":"2019-06-11","user":"Joe"}
]
let result = array.reduce(function(total, currentValue, currentIndex, arr) {
  let index = total.findIndex(function(entry) { return entry.code == currentValue.code; })
  if (index >= 0) { // entry already exists
    // check modified
    if (total[index].modifieddate > currentValue.modifieddate) { // already have most recent of the two
      total[index].Count += 1;
    } else { // need to replace with more recent
      currentValue.Count = total[index].Count + 1;
      total[index] = currentValue;
    }
  } else { // first record for this code
    currentValue.Count = 1;
    total.push(currentValue);
  }
  return total;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Here is a working [js-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/james_wasson/8byvp9rf/)

**Note:** Comments are made in code block

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you Mr. Wasson. Greatly appreciated sir!

Comment: No problem @Brian

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.reduce` to group the result set by each item's `code` property, incrementing `Count` as needed, then take the values from the accumulation object. Along the way, we perform a date comparison to determine which the most recent entry to include in the result.

```js
const data = [ {"ID":1,"code":"AAA","modifieddate":"2019-06-01","user":"John"}, {"ID":2,"code":"AAA","modifieddate":"2019-06-02","user":"Jane"}, {"ID":3,"code":"AAA","modifieddate":"2019-06-03","user":"Sue"}, {"ID":4,"code":"BBB","modifieddate":"2019-06-10","user":"Rick"}, {"ID":5,"code":"CCC","modifieddate":"2019-06-11","user":"Joe"} ];

const result = Object.values(data.reduce((a, e) => {
  if (!a[e.code]) {
    a[e.code] = {...e, Count: 0};
  }
  
  if (Date.parse(e.modifieddate) > Date.parse(a[e.code].modifieddate)) {
    a[e.code] = {...e, Count: a[e.code].Count};
  }
  
  a[e.code].Count++;
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

By the way, this is just a plain JS array we're working with, not JSON.

Comment: I don't see anything about `modifieddate` in this. The OP wants the most recent record as well.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. My output matches OP's exactly, so can you clarify where the discrepancy is?

Comment: Try changing the order of the first three records. You can probably just order it first then it will always get the correct result.

Comment: OK, I wasn't really clear what OP's intentions are since the example was trivial. Updated to match that requirement.

Comment: Nicely done. Thank you Mr. Gorlen. Greatly appreciated sir!